# How to connect to Salesforce Einstein using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, salesforce-einstein

I am trying to Integrate SalesForce Einstein (Sink) to Azure DataFactory (Source), Could anyone share knowledge article on this ?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Thanks @LeonYue, Sorry for the late response, Since there is no support to SalesForce Einstein we decided to use Azure Function to send data to SalesForce Einstein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory only support SalesForce, Salesforce Service Cloud and Salesforce Marketing Cloud. SalesForce Einstein is not supported for now, we can not integrate it to Data Factory.

Please reference: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)